# UIView is overlapping / creating again in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have  `UITableViewCell` that contains `UIView` (lets call it `CPView`)  which is created while `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. `CPView` is just a plain coloured view and for every cell its width is different (that's why needed to create in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

Problem is

1)The `CPView` 's colour gets darker every time cell loads (May be due to every time that cell creates the same view so overlapping effect).

2) The cell overlaps / inherits other cell's `CPView` (we can see this because of light and dark colour of two `CPView`).

How can I prevent cell to recreate if it already exist or creation of this `CPView` again?

**Edit**

```
- (void)configureCell:(CreditDebitCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //other code 

      UIView * CPView;

            if (CPView){

                CPView =nil;
            }
        else
        {

        CPView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x, cell.bounds.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width*[self.percentArray[indexPath.row] floatValue] ,cell.frame.size.height )];
        [CPView setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [CPView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:107/255.0 green:15/255.0 blue:47/255.0 alpha:0.5]];

        [cell addSubview: CPView];

      }

}
```

Comment: write your cellforRowAtIndexPath in question

Comment: Exactly.  Without seeing your *cellForRowAtIndexPath* function, there's no way to suggest a fix.  (I reckon you're missing a call to *dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier*.)

Comment: @MikeGledhill I have written  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method in cellForRowAtIndexPath .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is reuse of the cells - and therefore you get multiple views added to your cell view.

You can:

-remove subview
-check if subview exists and do/don't do anything.

You can check if the subview is there by going through subviews:

```
for (UIView *v in cell.contentView.subview) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[CPView class]]) {
        // remove or flag that it exists
    }
}
```

But I think that you should handle this in your cell - not your view controller that implements table view delegate. Better tell cell to use some view/hide some view based on some kind of logic then to do that inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: After changing the logic the cell can now create the view only once . Thanks @nick .

Answer (score 0):

According to your i `question(without cellforRowAtIndexpath)` i can assume that you should check every time something like in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
  if(cpView){

       cpView = nil;
  }

  // alloc again with required size for particular row.
```

Comment: I am creating `CPView ` in cellForRowAtIndexPath so every time it comes nil .

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass of your `UITableViewCell` and make a property of it that will reference your `CPView`. This will now let you have a better control whether your subclassed cell does / doesn't have any `CPView` that needs to be added.

Comment: I have tried adding `CPView ` in IB . But Its frame is not changing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` . If  width can change in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  this problem would not occur . I have also tried to change frame in `viewDidLayoutSubview` . But nothing is reflecting .

Comment: I was not refering to your `CPView` in the IB. I said that you should create a subclass of the `UITableViewCell` on which you will then state as the class of the cell in your IB or storyboard.

Comment: This is the exact answer on what NickCatib said - handle it inside your cell. Your accepted answer is correct but this is a better way of flagging the existence of your `CPViiew` inside your cell rather than looping through all its subviews.

Comment: I have tried that also referring the view to uitableviewcell class . But overlapping was still happening  . Very unexpected behaviour was coming .